# Sending values from popup child to parent in javascript

Tags: javascript, popup

**EDIT**

So I've find more than one mistake, and there was a lot, I've corrected all and I think that the only problem that I have right now is linked only to this functions

**EDIT END**

I'm trying to pass multiple variable from a child popup page to its parent. So in parent page the user can do many things, one of them is to open a popup that allow them to select five different value and this value are in my DB related to the users, and once selected at least once of them, I want to pass it to the parent page. So I've tried reading some topic on this board and nothing seems to work for me. Now I try to post here the parent and the child page.

PARENT

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function selectValue()
{
    // open popup window and pass field id
    window.open('/main2.php?page=lancio_chat','popuppage',
      'width=400,toolbar=1,resizable=1,scrollbars=yes,height=400,top=100,left=100');
}


function updateValue(val1, val2, val3, val4, val5)
{
    // this gets called from the popup window and updates the field with a new value
    document.getElementById('id1').value = val1;
    document.getElementById('id2').value = val2;
    document.getElementById('id3').value = val3;
    document.getElementById('id4').value = val4;
    document.getElementById('id5').value = val5;

}
</script>
<div class="casella_chat">
        <input type="button" name="send_choise" onClick="selectValue()" value="Open PopUp"/>
</div>
```

CHILD

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function sendValue(value1, value2, value3, value4, value5)
{
    window.opener.updateValue(value1, value2, value3, value4, value5);
    window.close();
}
</script>

<?php
if($_POST['op']='modify'){
    $val1 = $_POST['val1'];
    $val2 = $_POST['val2'];
    $val3 = $_POST['val3'];
    $val4 =  $_POST['val4'];
    $val5 =  $_POST['val5']; 
    <script type="text/javascript">
         SendValue(<?php echo $id_jutsu1_c; ?>,<?php echo $id_jutsu2_c; ?>,<?php echo $id_jutsu3_c; ?>,<?php echo $id_abilita_c; ?>,<?php echo $id_oggetto_c ; ?>)
    </script>
}
?>  
<div class="page_body">
    <?php //SELECT OF THE VALUES 1 LINKED TO THE USER ?>
    <div class='form_label'>
       <?php echo "Values 1: "; ?>
    </div>
    <div class='form_field'>
       <select name="val1" id="val1">
       <option value="no_value"></option>
       <?php while(//FETCHING ARRAY){ ?>
       <option value="<?php echo $ARRAY['id']; ?>"/><?php echo $ARRAY['nome']; ?></option>
       <?php }
            gdrcd_query($query, 'free');

       ?>
       </select>
    </div>

<div class="page_body">
    <?php //SELECT OF THE VALUES 2 LINKED TO THE USER ?>
    <div class='form_label'>
       <?php echo "Values 2: "; ?>
    </div>
    <div class='form_field'>
       <select name="val2" id="val2">
       <option value="no_value"></option>
       <?php while(//FETCHING ARRAY){ ?>
       <option value="<?php echo $ARRAY['id']; ?>"/><?php echo $ARRAY['nome']; ?></option>
       <?php }
            gdrcd_query($query, 'free');

       ?>
       </select>
    </div>

<div class="page_body">
    <?php //SELECT OF THE VALUES 3 LINKED TO THE USER ?>
    <div class='form_label'>
       <?php echo "Values 3: "; ?>
    </div>
    <div class='form_field'>
       <select name="val3" id="val3">
       <option value="no_value"></option>
       <?php while(//FETCHING ARRAY){ ?>
       <option value="<?php echo $ARRAY['id']; ?>"/><?php echo $ARRAY['nome']; ?></option>
       <?php }
            gdrcd_query($query, 'free');

       ?>
       </select>
    </div>

<div class="page_body">
    <?php //SELECT OF THE VALUES 4 LINKED TO THE USER ?>
    <div class='form_label'>
       <?php echo "Values 4: "; ?>
    </div>
    <div class='form_field'>
       <select name="val4" id="val4">
       <option value="no_value"></option>
       <?php while(//FETCHING ARRAY){ ?>
       <option value="<?php echo $ARRAY['id']; ?>"/><?php echo $ARRAY['nome']; ?></option>
       <?php }
            gdrcd_query($query, 'free');

       ?>
       </select>
    </div>

<div class="page_body">
    <?php //SELECT OF THE VALUES 5 LINKED TO THE USER ?>
    <div class='form_label'>
       <?php echo "Values 5: "; ?>
    </div>
    <div class='form_field'>
       <select name="val5" id="val5">
       <option value="no_value"></option>
       <?php while(//FETCHING ARRAY){ ?>
       <option value="<?php echo $ARRAY['id']; ?>"/><?php echo $ARRAY['nome']; ?></option>
       <?php }
            gdrcd_query($query, 'free');

       ?>
       </select>
    </div>
```

So what I'm making wrong on this?